# What is the best way to quickly extract data from SSMS to Excel without distortion?

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, ssms

I am running bunch of queries every day and need to quickly send the output via Excel to user. 
What I do now is straight from SSMS:  Highlight the data  --> right click "Copy with Headers"  and pasting it into Excel.

[image]

But the problem is sometimes money column displays as date, long strings breaking up, numbers displays as scientific formula. I can go on and on.

I'm trying to write vba code to extract what I need, but it will be too much to write code for every piece of code I need to extract.

So what would be the best and easiest way to copy and paste data from SSMS to Excel on a regular basis without and make sure data in Excel stays same as in SQL? Without any changes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From inside Excel you can connect to SQL Server and load data onto a worksheet.

For older versions of Excel use Microsoft Query
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e

For newer versions of Excel use Power Query
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-query-to-an-Excel-worksheet-Power-Query-ca69e0f0-3db1-4493-900c-6279bef08df4